# Foundation Dropdown Button Not Styling Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I can't get my Foundation dropdown button to work (it appears the CSS isn't loading correctly).  I've tried various ways of implementing the button, including the following code, which is more or less cut and pasted from the Foundation website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<div href="#" class="large button dropdown">
  Dropdown Button
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Dropdown Item</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Last Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What it ends up look like is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFt6k.png

(I don't have enough reputation to post an image directly- sorry)

Just to be clear, I've ensure that the links are correct, and have also tried using CDNs instead just to make sure it's not a linking issue.

Chrome console throws up no errors, ditto with gulp.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is a div in your code but Foundation documentation has it as a button element (inspect the first drop down button on this page to see it working: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown_buttons.html):

```
<button data-dropdown="drop" aria-controls="drop" aria-expanded="true" class="tiny button dropdown">Dropdown Button</button>
```

I reckon if you adjust your button to match the above then it will work. Foundation's javascript needs the aria roles and classes and the button element.

Comment: My goodness dude- thanks for the link!  You are right.  What happened is when I googled 'Foundation Components' it led me to Foundation 3 code, here

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/buttons.php

I neglected to notice it's not the current version of Foundation.  Thanks again, I really appreciate it!  Puzzled for days over this.